# How can I store files or any form of data on a phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Id like to build a Phonegap app which allows users to first access programs from a web-server(already achieved) and also provide the option to download those programs for later use offline. These programs are comprised of of images, html, js, and css files. Is it possible permanently store any files or data on a Phonegap app? If so, please expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible permanently store any files or data on a Phonegap app?

YES. You can find [phonegap storage API details here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Rather than this I use to write into text / xml files for storing data. [This documentation helps you](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File)

But in your case you need to download programs and data. This depends up on your logic. You need to derive some logic for that.